# Apache 2.4.6 CentOS VirtualHost Issue

Tags: php, apache-2.4, virtualhost, centos7

I have a CentOS 7 Box with Apache 2.4.6 installed on it, after installing apache i was able to access the default page via the ip address, but after i add a virtual host, i am unable to access the default page or index.php

Check List -

I have set all sorts of permissions on my root folder, did 775, 777 and 755, but its of no user.

The user of my root folder is axis:axis, its not apache:apache or axis:apache

I have tried accessing both .html and .php files, but no help

I tried making a directory entry in http.conf, but it also did not work

Here is my virtual host entry -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
         php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
         php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>

ServerAdmin admin@demosite.com
ServerName www.demosite.com
ServerAlias www.demosite.com
ServerRoot /home/axis/public_html
DocumentRoot /home/axis/public_html
<Directory /home/axis/public_html>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#LogLevel info ssl:warn
 ErrorLog /home/axis/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /home/axis/logs/requests.log
```

Please help me, i dont have any idea what apache has changed in version 2.4.6

ApacheCTL Output -

```
# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80 www.demosite.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/demosite.com.conf:2)
ServerRoot: "/home/demosite/public_html"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/home/demosite/public_html/logs/error_log"
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48
```

Comment: </VirtualHost>
Forgot to put the last line of my code, also the CustomLogs is disabled

Comment: I am getting the following error - Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: Also add the output of `apachectl -S` to your post

Comment: i have put the apache ctl response

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake. I swithced the documentroot and serverroot.

it needs to be -

ServerRoot /home/axis/
DocumentRoot /home/axis/public_html

after making the above changes i was able to access my websites

thanks for your help